# Angular-intro.js not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intro.js

While going from step-to-step i have applied `ng-if` condition on step... how to continue if any of if condition fails in `angular-intro.js`??

```
<a ng-intro-options="IntroOptions" ng-intro-method="CallMe"
     ng-intro-oncomplete="CompletedEvent" ng-intro-onexit="ExitEvent"
     ng-intro-onchange="ChangeEvent" ng-intro-onbeforechange="BeforeChangeEvent"
     ng-intro-autostart="false" ng-click="CallMe();">
<span class="pull-right">
<i class="fa fa-question fa-md" aria-hidden="true" title="Help"></i>
</span>
</a>
<div id="step1">welcome</div>
<div ng-if="admin" id="step2">hello nice to meet you Admin</div>
<div id="step3">list of tasks for the day {{user}}</div>
```

and in my `controller`:

```
$scope.IntroOptions = {
    steps:[
    {
      element: '#step1',
      intro: 'Search data from current list. Advanced Search helps you find data with respective columns.',
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    {
      element: '#step2',
      intro: 'Click on Add icon to add new Channel.',
      position: 'left'
    },
    {
      element: '#step3',
      intro: 'List of all channels.',
      position: 'top'
    }
    ],
    showStepNumbers: false,
    showBullets: false,
    exitOnOverlayClick: true,
    exitOnEsc:true,
    nextLabel: '<strong>NEXT!</strong>',
    prevLabel: '<span style="color:green">Previous</span>',
    skipLabel: 'Exit',
    doneLabel: 'Thanks'
  };
```

Its working perfectly when `ng-if` condition is '**admin**'.
But when if condition fails its ending with step1 how can I continue with step3 directly if `ng-if` condition fails.

Comment: use `ng-switch` instead of `ng-if`

Comment: tried with `ng-show`, `ng-switch` but nop not working still

Comment: Where you used multiple ng-if in your code? you have used ng-if only once

Comment: can you Precisely explain where i can use ng-switch in my code.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to I do with this code?

Comment: ng-show worked for me.